# delete a row when it reached the expiration date PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website which will reserve lots and then saves expiration date to table, when expiration date reached its deadline, it will delete the row. For example

**table: reservation

Reserve_date: 21 Feb 2017 4:00 PM

expiration: 22 Feb 2017 4:00 PM**

```
<?php
$date = date('d M Y h:i A'); //for example it's 22 Feb 2017 4:30 PM 

$sql = "DELETE FROM reservation WHERE expiration *do codes here*";
$conn->query($sql);

?>
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You might be be better off creating a trigger that fires on the specified date than trying to doing the delete with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, format of date is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS. So you need to store date in variable in this format

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Then you need to need to execute this query for deleting a row

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM reservation WHERE expiration = '$date' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that process to be independent and without any external intervention, I'm afraid you'll need to create a process in the server that check that every x time and delete expired rows.

If you have full access to the server, you can create a script (in php or other) with the deletion code and then create a cron line that execute the script every x seconds, minutes, hours... whatever time gap suits you better.

If you want to use php for the script, be sure your system has the dependencies required to execute php as scripts (without a web server). For example, in debian you would need php-cli package.